# AWS Lambda function not reading bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using AWS lambda function to read my JSON file. I have created a Lambda function which checks whether any new `.json` file is uploaded to `my.bucket`. If yes, then I am using that JSON file as per my requirement.

Below is my code snippet:

```
var response = await this.S3Client.GetObjectMetadataAsync(s3Event.Bucket.Name,  s3Event.Object.Key);
```

`s3Event.Bucket.Name` is my bucket name and `s3Event.Object.Key` is the JSON file which I am reading.

However, I am getting this error:

> Error getting object example.json from bucket my.bucket. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.

I'm using dot net core.

Comment: Have you verified that the object exists in the correct bucket? and that the bucket and AWS Lambda function is hosted in the same region?

Comment: yes it is @MalteR

Comment: Just for a sanity check, the bucket is in the same region you think it is? I often accidentally create resources in the default region, which then give that error because it was supposed to be in eu-west-1 :-)

Comment: Ah sorry @MalteR I just noticed you already asked that.

Comment: Off your question but found it important enough to tell you- regarding "which checks whether any new .json file is uploaded to my.bucket" - you don't need to to poll on the bucket for new uploaded files, you could just setup an event on that bucket that will trigger your lambda.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that it is not a permissions problem, you should also make sure the file/path name you are looking for matches *exactly*. S3 bucket and file names are case sensitive, whereas under windows they are generally not (and since you are coding in C# I assume you are coming from a windows point-of-view).

I have been caught in the case-sensitive 'trap' myself more than a handful of time...